# eloquent relationship and database or three way relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am struggling with setting up my database and eloquent relationships in a certain scenario.

This certain part of my application will be handling online orders.
basically i want an order to consist of multiple configured items.
i want configured items to consist of a base item (ex. a cheesburger) and also of toppings.

i have gone through several scenarios, but I am trying to make this as simple as possible. here is the quick and dirty story of what I have now.
I want a configured item to consist of three things. 1. the order id of the order it is associated with. 2. the menu item that it relates to (ex. cheeseburger, hotdog ) 3. and the toppings.

I am considering two tables that are full of relatively static information about the menu items and the toppings to be referenced from the configured item table.

I had originally considered creating a new menu item on every configured item, but I like the idea of just being able to look up items/toppings and applying them to a configured item. Im sorry if this is unclear. I am three days into this and my brain is absolutely in pain by now.

here are the relationships i am considering.

configured_item: belongsTo Order; hasOne menu_Item;

Menu_item: belongsToMany configured_item; hasMany toppings;

Toppings: belongsToMany configured_item;

I guess in a way my configured item table is a pivot table of sorts, but then it will need to be referenced by an order as well.

i know questions have been asked about three way relationships, but I cant find any info on tables that are relatively static like i am trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

I finally caved and used two pivot tables. it all works, but i cannot help but feel there is a better way to handle this. It seems a lot of people have similar issues and there is no clear cut solution.